# Block Internet Access for 1 User

Tags: ubuntu, internet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to restrict internet access for a particular user on the lan using iptables in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21650/how-to-restrict-internet-access-for-a-particular-user-on-the-lan-using-iptables)

I have 4 accounts on my computer (I have root access). I want to block off **ALL** internet access to one of the users. My computer connects to the internet primarily through Wi-Fi. The user should not be able to connect, surf the internet or even use the local network.
I found a solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21650/how-to-restrict-internet-access-for-a-particular-user-on-the-lan-using-iptables) but I'm not sure that would work for me. (Plus I need something simpler)

I am using Ubuntu 10.04

How do I do this without much tweaking? (Basically, I want a quick and simple solution)

I tried reading about Iptables but its beyond my knowledge.

Comment: I had included that link in my question but IPTables looks too confusing to use. Aah well, If there is nothing else I can use.

Comment: Iptables really is the best job for this. A single iptables command does it. All you have to do is change that `--uid-owner` value to match the user you want to block and youre done. Wanting something simpler doesnt make the answer wrong (plus, you dont get much simpler than that).

Comment: I just hoped for a nice GUI. But considering that isn't available/possible, I think iptables is a compromise.

Comment: if you need a gui, there's `firewall-config` for `firewalld`. Check this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/676996/313554) on the duplicate question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have `iptables` and `connlimit` installed you can limit incoming connections for a certain range or a single IP:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -p ! tcp -m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.100-192.168.1.102 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 50 -j REJECT
ip6tables -I FORWARD -p ! tcp -m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.100-192.168.1.102 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 50 -j REJECT
```

This can reject incoming connections above 50 open sockets for IP x.x.x.100 to x.x.x.102. I'm not sure if you can change the value to reject all incoming connections. I use this basically to throttle download for a single IP.

Answer (score 1):

If you install one of the parental controls apps e.g. [Nanny](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2010/08/install-nanny-parental-control-system-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx/) you can restrict the amount of time a user has access to the Internet to zero/never.
There are other parental controls apps, don't have one in particular to recommend but this should give you the level of control you want, with the simplicity of a GUI app.

Comment: Nanny doesn't work. I tried giving the user 0 time on web browser, internet messaging and stuff. I rebooted and 5 mins later, that user was gladly surfing rage comics.