# How to restrict internet access on Kali Linux 2.0

Tags: kali-linux, internet

My son who is still in his teen age recently started learning to work on Kali Linux at our home PC. However as I have configured WiFi through router, due to this the computer's internet remains "always ON".

As my PC is having dual boot, I have installed a software to restrict the internet access on Win7, which every time asks for password to access the internet. But what should I do to get the same on Linux?

Comment: You could always set up a web proxy

Comment: @ ryekayo :-->  Can you please elaborate about how to set up proxy there?

Answer (score 0):

If your son has a user account on your Linux machine and you have an administrative account on the same machine, you can use iptables quite comfortably.

I don't want to copy & paste the answer, but here is the [link to the answer on stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21660/81553).